# Add XML element to complex XML file with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, updates

Have a very complex task for Powershell on remote work for me. It's hard to explain but I will try.
I have XML file with complex structure (it's a file with settings for Visual Studio):

```
<UserSettings>
<ToolsOptions>
<ToolsOptionsCategory RegisteredName="Environment" name="Environment">
</ToolsOptionsCategory>
</ToolsOptions>
</UserSettings>
```

The task is add to section "ToolsOptionsCategory" following sub-node:

```
<ToolsOptionsSubCategory PackageName="VS Setup Composition" RegisteredName="ProductUpdates" name="ProductUpdates">
<PropertyValue name="IsBackground">true</PropertyValue>
</ToolsOptionsSubCategory>
```

I tried to AppendChild and CreateElement, but I don't have an idea how to add such attributes as "PackageName" and "RegistereName". This subnode is absent from the target file and I need to add it.
I would be great if you can help me and show me the way.

Thank you in advance! Be health and stay at home :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For demo, I'm using a Here-String

```
[xml]$xml = @"
<UserSettings>
<ToolsOptions>
<ToolsOptionsCategory RegisteredName="Environment" name="Environment">
</ToolsOptionsCategory>
</ToolsOptions>
</UserSettings>
"@
```

In real life, you would load it from file with `[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path 'D:\config.xml'`

```
$node = $xml.UserSettings.ToolsOptions.ToolsOptionsCategory
# update the attributes for this node
$node.SetAttribute("PackageName", "VS Setup Composition")
$node.SetAttribute("RegisteredName", "ProductUpdates")
$node.SetAttribute("name", "ProductUpdates")
# create the new sub node (XmlElement)
$newNode = $xml.CreateElement("PropertyValue")
$newNode.SetAttribute("name", "IsBackground")
$newNode.InnerText = "true"
# add this new subnode to the 'ToolsOptionsCategory' node
$node.AppendChild($newNode)

$xml.Save('D:\newConfig.xml')
```

Result:

```
<UserSettings>
  <ToolsOptions>
    <ToolsOptionsCategory RegisteredName="ProductUpdates" name="ProductUpdates" PackageName="VS Setup Composition">
      <PropertyValue name="IsBackground">true</PropertyValue>
    </ToolsOptionsCategory>
  </ToolsOptions>
</UserSettings>
```

Comment: Thanks! Great! I've checked your answer and have small changes regarding this current situation. Your answer is working!

Comment: @Tube Thanks for the nice feedback. Stay safe!

Comment: This is good. I included a `ToolsOptionsSubCategory` sub node as well from the question. I guess it doesn't really matter if its not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do is as well. I've added comments to explain the approach.

```
# Create XML object to load data into
$xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument

# Load in XML file
$xml.Load("test.xml")

# Get root tools node to add children
$toolsRootNode = $xml.UserSettings.ToolsOptions.ToolsOptionsCategory

# Store attributes in a hashtable
$toolsAttributes = [ordered]@{
    PackageName="Setup Composition"
    RegisteredName="ProductUpdates"
    name="ProductUpdates"
}

# Set each attribute from hashtable
$toolsSubNode = $xml.CreateElement("ToolsOptionsSubCategory")
foreach ($kvp in $toolsAttributes.GetEnumerator())
{
    $toolsSubNode.SetAttribute($kvp.Key, $kvp.Value)
}

# Create property sub node
$propertyNode = $xml.CreateElement("PropertyValue")
$propertyNode.SetAttribute("name", "IsBackground")
$propertyNode.InnerText = "true"

# Append property node to tools sub node
$toolsSubNode.AppendChild($propertyNode)

# Finally add tools sub node to root node
$toolsRootNode.AppendChild($toolsSubNode)

# Save to new output XML file
$xml.Save("output.xml")
```

**output.xml**

```
<UserSettings>
  <ToolsOptions>
    <ToolsOptionsCategory RegisteredName="Environment" name="Environment">
      <ToolsOptionsSubCategory PackageName="Setup Composition" RegisteredName="ProductUpdates" name="ProductUpdates">
        <PropertyValue name="IsBackground">true</PropertyValue>
      </ToolsOptionsSubCategory>
    </ToolsOptionsCategory>
  </ToolsOptions>
</UserSettings>
```

Comment: Thank you @RoadRunner, I've checked your solution and it is also working :) Comments are very helpful because now I really know how to deal with XML and Powershell.

Comment: @Tube No worries. Glad it was useful to you.